# Is there a canonical jQuery $(document).ready() question?

Tags: discussion, canonical

One of the most common errors that jQuery programmers make is forgetting to put their code inside `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`. The most recent I noticed is [JSFiddle script not working locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29000701/jsfiddle-script-not-working-locally).

Is there a canonical question that we can use to close these as duplicates? I tried searching, but the terms are used so much in jQuery-related questions and answers that it's impossible to find something specific to this.

I've found some questions that answer generic questions about `$(document).ready`, like

[jQuery document.ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657572/jquery-document-ready/9657629#9657629)

[$(document).ready shorthand](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6004129/1026459)

[window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready?rq=1)

but they presume you know that this exists and answer more detailed questions about how it works. I was hoping for one directly answering questions of the form "Why doesn't my jQuery code work?"

Comment: How about... you create one?

Comment: I might, I just don't want to reinvent the wheel if there already is a good one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6004129/1026459 would be the best question, perhaps you can post an answer there if you feel the post needs more information.

Comment: Also for consideration would be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready?rq=1

Comment: You can always add this information to the tag wiki. [Edit: seems like it is already there: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info ]

Comment: @SalmanA That's nice. What would be the appropriate way to refer to that in a close reason?

Comment: If you create a canon, please specifically mention that jsFiddle usually auto-magically adds `$(function(){ ` or `$(window).load(function(){`

Comment: I assume you want a queation like, what is `$(document).ready` ?  Wouldn't that question show lack of effort? Question would rather sound like, where to start learning jquery

Comment: No, that's NOT what I want. I want to mark questions as duplicate of something. That something should be a question where they didn't use `$(document).ready()` and the answer is to wrap the code in it, with a good explanation of why this is necessary. What I'm looking for is question like the one I just answered, but better written and with a more detailed answer than the one I wrote really quickly, so that it will serve as a great reference.

Comment: I'm waiting for someone to make a feature request (or to bump one) which makes the tag wiki required reading.

Comment: That's a pretty long tag wiki, I think people will just give up on web programming if they have to do that. Which might not be a bad thing... My wishlist is for an electric shock to people who post Javascript questions without checking the console for errors first.

Comment: @Barmar in order to close as a duplicate, you need a duplicate question. And there are many. Just find the most _generic_ one and mark as duplicate (I'll see if I can find one).

Comment: @SalmanA That's what I'm asking: does anyone know a good, generic one to use. I tried to find one, but the best I could find were more general questions about how it works, like the ones mentioned above.

Comment: @Barmar add this to the list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062246/when-should-i-use-jquerys-document-ready-function. I must admit I did not find a generic question, so please (wait a little, then) create a canonical question.

Comment: i too didnt find any  generic one, probably you should create one @Barmar

Comment: Maybe this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193338/what-is-the-correct-jquery-document-ready-wrap needs a lot of work, though

Comment: Why not make a canonical that is less library biased? surely jquery isn't the only time  you have this problem, and using $(document).ready isn't the only (or even "the best") solution to it. then there are cases where the same *problem* is happening, but it isn't related to document ready at all, it's simply a race condition where you tried to work with an element that hasn't been appended yet.

Comment: I don't know if the problem is common with other libraries, because I don't read too many of those questions. But with jQuery we see this error on a daily basis.

Comment: @TylerH In that question she's already using `$(document).ready()`, so how would it be an appropriate duplicate for questions that don't use it?

Comment: Actually, the question that one refers to might be good: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192882/jquery-show-and-hide-doesnt-work-something-is-missing-and-i-cant-figure-it-out

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034342/jquery-onclick-on-div/7034384#7034384 what about this one? Here's my search terms, seems to be turning up a few good options:  `is:answer score:10 use $(document).ready(`

Comment: @KevinB It would be great except it suggests the obsolete `.live()` method.

Comment: I particularly like this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008843/start-javascript-code-with-function-etc/12008894#12008894 too bad the question doesn't match.

Comment: Any existing great answer to this is going to be old and likely to mention .live() since it was a valid solution to the problem at the time.

Comment: @KevinB - If you are thinking about one with less library bias, this seems like a good candidate as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready/3698214#3698214

Comment: A very complete answer was posted yesterday:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716653/js-jquery-cant-detect-html-elements-and-says-they-are-undefined